# unbound method check_heater_data() must be called with ChartData instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, django

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong while calling some data from python script to Django views. Currently I get the error in the title. My relevant code is the following:

```
#views.py

def highcharts(request, chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 500):
    data = ChartData.check_heater_data()
    #rest of the code ...
```

And the python script:

```
from .models import Heater
class ChartData(object):    
    def check_heater_data(self):
        data = {'id': [], 'temperature_max': [],
             'temperature_min': []}

        valves = Heater.objects.all()

        for unit in valves:
            data['id'].append(unit.id)
            data['temperature_max'].append(unit.temperature_max)
            data['temperature_min'].append(unit.temperature_min)

        return data
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is to get data from MySQL and append it to a dictionary. After I'd like to use this dictionary in highcharts to display my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *instantiate* `ChartData` before you can use its methods:

```
def highcharts(...):
    instance = ChartData() # creates an instance
    data = instance.check_heater_data() # now you can call this
```

Alternatively, you can declare `check_heater_data()` as a *class method* (a method that can be accessed without creating an instance) and then you can call `check_heater_data()` without instantiating it.

```
class ChartData(object): 
    @classmethod   
    def check_heater_data(self):
        ...
```

which lets you do `ChartData.check_heater_data()` with no issues.

If you want *minimal* changes and don't want the overhead of creating an object instance, go for the second method.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. May I ask another question in case you know it; after that fix the screen is blank where graph should be. After inspection i found out that next to my values from db there is "L" next to each number, e.g. 1L, 2L, 3L, etc. Do you know if this might be the problem of the script? Best regards, Narn

Comment: @narn Unfortunately, since we don't have access to your code, can't comment. Would recommend you ask as separate question with relevant code associated. However, off the top of my head, it sounds like you should remove the `L`s and convert to `int`. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will google first a bit and if I won't find a fix i'll ask a separate question. Thanks nonetheless. I will also try converting to float.